# Ansible execute commands

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, ansible

I have configured a fully distributed hadoop cluster using ansible, but I want to configure ansible to execute the next command too.

I use the next to execute zookeeper, but I have the next error.

```
- name: ejecutar zkServer.sh
  become_user: vagrant
  shell: sh /opt/zookeeper-3.4.7/bin/zkServer.sh



TASK: [ejecutar | ejecutar zkServer.sh] *************************************** 
failed: [172.16.8.211] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sh /opt/zookeeper-3.4.7/bin/zkServer.sh", "delta": "0:00:00.006246", "end": "2016-01-18 14:28:44.181146", "rc": 2, "start": "2016-01-18 14:28:44.174900", "warnings": []}
stderr: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.7/bin/zkServer.sh: 81: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.7/bin/zkEnv.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the next/previous commands". This just looks like something from a terminal, not anything related to Ansible

Comment: @cricket_007 yes what I want is to execute thats terminal commands using ansible. Is it not possible?

Comment: It is possible... Have you looked here? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_commands_modules.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Okey, thanks very much, I would try if some of there works. :)

Comment: Welcome. If you run into issues with Ansible, update your question with the actual Ansible tasks

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't use anyone of thats commands modules to execute zkServer.sh. Can you help me?

Comment: According to the error, it doesn't look like anything you have done wrong (unless you wrote or made changes to the file). `zkEnv.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working like with the next command:

```
- name: ejecutar zkServer.sh
  become_user: vagrant
  command: "/opt/zookeeper-3.4.7/bin/zkServer.sh restart"
```